# What parameter tells whiteness of a monitor?

Tags: display

Some monitors have good white. The ones I have used include DELL 2435, ACER S271HL, DELL U3415W, and ASUS PB287Q. But some are just yellowish no matter how you adjust them.

If I want to buy a monitor online, how do I know whether it has a good white? Which parameter / specification should I look at?

Comment: There are lots of things that affect the color, even dimming the backlight if it has an ambient light sensor.  The monitor may have a built-in menu with a mode selector that can change a lot of the appearance characteristics.  You also may be able to adjust the color in the video driver.  If that doesn't have fine tuning of the color profile, there are third party utilities (or maybe even one provided with the monitor), that can do that.  Because the raw color can be hit or miss, people who do serious image editing routinely calibrate any monitor rather than rely on the raw color.

Comment: I did try to calibrate in different ways (OSD, software), but my experience is that some monitors are just yellowish no matter how you adjust it.

Comment: My main monitor I've had for a few years.  It was nice and white when I got it and the color has drifted to yellowish as it's aged.  Your question prompted me to tweak its built-in menu.  I've also often seen several new monitors of a same model side by side in computer stores, and the colors were a little different between them.  I suspect that other people's experience, or what the monitor looks like right out of the box may not be a reliable basis for expecting long-term color accuracy.  With any monitor, you pretty much need to plan on tweaking it over time if the color bothers you.

Comment: I just checked the menu on mine.  It has a color tone setting.  Warm is very yellow and cool is very blue.  It could be that different monitors are set one way or the other by default.  Just something to check.

Comment: Yes. I have tried that. It did make some differences to that monitor, but comparing to another monitor, it's still yellowish. If you have two side-by-side, the difference is very obvious. Some monitors just have good white, some don't. I don't know what is the major factor there.

Comment: If a new one is yellowish, that's a good sign not to buy it.  Otherwise, the biggest factor is probably luck.  :-)  Anyway, hope you get some useful advice.

Comment: In theory its colour temperature. In practice, you want one that's factory calibrated and adjust it to fit. But a lot of professional monitors lean yellow rather than blue.

Comment: Is there a way to know whether it leans yellow or blue when I am shopping online?